# How can I get grep -n -o to print the line number for matches occurring on the same line?

Tags: awk, grep, zsh, gnu

I am searching through a file containing sequences on each line. I want to grep for each line containing a 'C' and output the line number : C.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
grep -v ">" chr22.fa | grep -o -n  "[C|c]" | less
```

Out:

```
210201:C
C
C
C
210202:C
C
C
C
C
C
C
210203:C
C
C
C
C
210204:C
C
C
C
C
C
```

And so on...

What I'd like is:

```
210201:C
210201:C
210201:C
210201:C
210202:C
210202:C
210202:C
210202:C
210202:C
210202:C
210202:C
210203:C
210203:C
210203:C
210203:C
210203:C
210204:C
210204:C
210204:C
210204:C
210204:C
210204:C
```

etc...

The documentation I have found online suggests that this should already be happening with the `-n` option so I'm thinking there's some environment variable or grep setting I need to change, but I can't figure out what it is. I am using a zsh shell on Mac OS.

Comment: With bash on Linux I get the desired outpt with no modifications. Can you try `bash` or another `grep`?

Comment: Am I correct to understand that you actually want to have the sequence number and the total times "C" appears in the sequence?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know how often C occurs on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU grep produces the output you are looking for. By contrast, BSD grep does not output the line number for additional `-o` matches on the same line.

Try the `ggrep` command or install GNU grep.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 3):

In case you are ok with `awk`, this should be an easy task for it. Since no samples are given so this is not tested, a fair warning.

```
awk '/>/{next} /c|C/{line=FNR} {print line":C"}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk` to replace both `grep` commands:

```
awk -F '[Cc]' '!/>/ {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print NR ":" FS}' chr22.fa
```

Answer (score 1):

From analyzing the code of in the OP, it seems a fasta file is being processed. I assume the line-number the OP is referencing, actually means the sequence number. Furthermore, the OP most likely works with single-line sequences. Assuming the true question is:

> Given a [fasta](/questions/tagged/fasta) file, how can I return the sequence number of the sequences containing the letter "C" or "c"?

In this case, the answer would be:

```
awk '/>/{c++;next} match($0,/[cC]/) { print c }' file
```

If the OP is also interested in the total times this character appears, he can do:

```
awk '/>/{c++;next}(n=gsub(/[cC]/,"c",$0)) { print c,n }' file
```

If the OP would be processing fasta files where the sequences span multiple lines, the awk lines would be:

```
awk '/>/{c++;p=1;next} p && match($0,/[cC]/) { print c; p=0 }' file
awk '/>/{if(n)print c,n;c++;n=0;next}{n+=gsub(/[cC]/,"c",$0)}END{if(n) print c,n}' file
```

While this is not really exactly what the OP describes, this will print the sequence number `c` and the total amount of times the character `c` or `C` appears in the sequence. This will not print the letter `"C"` as that is a bit weird to print what you are searching for.